# Only Create Instance of Object when db result is not null

Tags: vb.net

I'm newish when it comes to .net and this has me stumped as to how to deal with it as efficiently as possible.

I'm retrieving a number of records via Entity Framework and then creating multiple instances of an "issue" object which are added to an observable collection.

Within the "issue" object is a subclass called "assignedto" which simply contains an integer and a string. However it will not always be the case that the assignedTo record in the db will be complete, i.e. Entity Framework returns nothing which is correct:

```
    Public Sub LoadIssueData(ByRef parIssueItems As ObservableCollection(Of Issue))


        Using db As New pResolveConnection
            Dim dbIssueList As New List(Of String)
            Try
                Dim qry = From a In db.vCurrentLogs
                          Where a.statusID <> constClosedIssueStatus
                          Select a
                          Order By a.createdDate Descending


                For Each res In qry
                    dbIssueList.Add(res.ID)
                    Dim issueIndex As Integer
                    issueIndex = GetIssueIndex(res.ID, parIssueItems)

                    If issueIndex = -1 Then
                        parIssueItems.Add(New Issue(res.ID, res.title, res.createdDate, res.CreatedByUserName, res.CreatedByTeamName, res.CreatedByDeptName, New AssignedTo(res.assignedToID, res.assignedToName)))
                    Else
                        Dim oldIssue As New Issue(parIssueItems.Item(issueIndex))
                        Dim newIssue As New Issue(res.ID, res.title, res.createdDate, res.CreatedByUserName, res.CreatedByTeamName, res.CreatedByDeptName, New AssignedTo(res.assignedToID, res.assignedToName))

                        VerifyIssue(oldIssue, newIssue, parIssueItems, issueIndex)

                    End If
                Next

                'Some way to remove issues no longer in db



            Catch Ex As Exception
                MsgBox(Ex.Message)
                Throw
            Finally

                db.Dispose()
                dbIssueList = Nothing


            End Try

        End Using

        LoadIssueNotes(parIssueItems)

    End Sub
```

The error returned is nullable object must have a value, which is correct when it trys to create the new instance of "assignedto" as res.assignedToID is nothing.

In this case what I want it to do as create the "issue" instance but not create the assignedto instance so it is nothing with the holding class.

I cannot for the life of me think of an easy way to do this. I have a vba background so in my hed I just want to wrap do nz(res.assignedToID,0). Though there is no NZ in .net and that would still create an instance of that object anyway which is what I want to avoid.

Any pointers would be helpful.

Comment: Can you just check the parameter value before adding it inside of Issue? If it is null then add "" instead

Comment: Where exactly are you getting the error?

Comment: Sorry I get the error when initialising adding the items to the observable collection: parIssueItems.add ....

Comment: OK I have semi answered my own question but to be honest it is not that satisfactory. If I change the type in the assignedto class from integer to integer? then it just creates a new instance of the assignedto object where the ID for the class is nothing. I can live with this but I would prefer it not to create an instance of the object at all.

Answer (score 0):

Going to mark this as answered as after further thought I believe the solution in my comment is correct and works.

The solution is to create a nullable type , i.e. suffix ? onto your type when you the compiler creates a related db entity that may return a nullable value. You will know if you have option strict on as the compiler will complain.

After some thought, having the sub class create a new instance but with null field values is a perfectly acceptable solution to this.